# ¿Cuál sería un buen icono para Spanish Language?

Tags: discusión, petición-de-funcionalidad, site-evaluation, diseño

No sé en qué momento puede un sitio de Stack Exchange cambiar su icono por defecto (el bocadillo azul con las siglas del sitio) por un icono personalizado. No sé si es a partir de salir de *beta*, y tampoco sé quién se encarga de diseñar ese icono. Sin embargo, eso no me impide tirar de imaginación, sacar el pequeño diseñador gráfico que llevo dentro (muy malo, eso sí), y pensar en cuál sería un buen icono para el sitio.

Por supuesto, evitar a toda costa cualquier referencia a colores de banderas, dado que el idioma se habla en medio mundo. Tras ver que el icono del sitio [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) es la "a" del hiragana dentro de un círculo, parece obvio tirar de nuestra "ñ" para el mismo, ya que es lo que más representa al idioma y es universalmente reconocido. Pero ¿cuáles serían los detalles? O si no, ¿a alguien se le ocurre algún otro motivo para el icono del sitio?

Propuesta así a lo loco (sin pensar mucho) homenaje a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/):

[image]

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from last week: [Custom Spanish Language design and logo - Information gathering](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4448/30873) :)

Comment: Update: [New design launched](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/30873) (which includes a redesigned `ñ` favicon!)